# Does tbb::concurrent_unordered_map::unsafe_erase invalidate any existing iterators?

Tags: c++, concurrency, thread-safety, hashmap, tbb

I see that `tbb::concurrent_unordered_map` hews pretty close to `std::unordered_map` while being safe for concurrency. I also know that `unsafe_erase` is not concurrent-safe with `insert` etc. The iterator docs also state that any existing iterators are still valid with `insert`, `find` etc.

The question is, **does `unsafe_erase` invalidate any other iterator than the one it is asked to erase?**

`std::unordered_map` and `std::map` certainly have this behavior, but it's not specified in the `concurrent_unordered_map` docs anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tbb::unsafe_erase does not invalidate other iterators.  This is a property that we should document.

The reason that it does not invalidate other iterators is that the underlying implementation is a [split-ordered list](http://www.cs.ucf.edu/~dcm/Teaching/COT4810-Spring2011/Literature/SplitOrderedLists.pdf), and an iterator just points into that list.

Comment: Thanks for a definitive answer. I was intending to use it for a cache, together with a queue of map iterators to determine the oldest entry to expire. Obviously if erasing the oldest entry would invalidate the queue, I would end up having to refresh the queue for every erasure or use a key instead.